# Bootbox : issue with dialog width

Tags: angularjs, bootbox

I have a bootbox :

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "Commentaire présentation",
    inputType: 'textarea',
    className: "mediumBootbox",
    value :suivi.commentaireEstimation,
    callback: function (result) {
        ...
    }
});
```

and its css :

```
.mediumBootbox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

The problem is that the dialog width never exceeds 600px even if I set it to 1000px.

Is it normal?

Comment: try max-width: 1000px!important

Comment: you're trying to change the width of 'modal-content' ?